# VueJS close Hamburger Menu on Route Change

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a simple VueJS App with a Navigation Bar from Bootstrap:

```
<template>
  <header id="header">
    <nav class="navbar mynavbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="logo" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><router-link to="/home"><a>Home</a></router-link></li>
             <li><router-link to="/about"><a>About Us</a></router-link></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
  </header>
</template>
```

Now I want to ensure that when I change the route, the Bootstrap Menu gets closed. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: what about `<router-link to="/path" @click.native="closeModal()" ....` ?

Comment: @Gintoki nothing happens :/

Comment: what are you calling? closeModal() ?

Comment: I'm also interested in an option that waits for the next page to load, or at least the current one to transition out before the close function

Answer (score 32):

Instead of adding event handlers to every `router-link`, you can simply watch the `$route` property for changes:

```
<script>
export default {
  watch: {
    '$route' () {
      $('#navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hey there, is there a solution without  jquery?

Comment: Wthout JQuery : document.querySelector("#navbar-collapse").classList.toggle("active");

Answer (score 19):

Without Bootstrap and jQuery, can be easily achieved using class toggle and watch route changes.

```
<a role="button" class="navbar-burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" 
    @click="toggledNav = !toggledNav"
>
   <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
```

**Script:**

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      toggledNav: false
    }
  },
  watch: {
    '$route' () {
      this.toggledNav = false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me but I had to add v-bind:class="{ 'show': toggledNav }" to the collapse div.

Comment: @DylanGlockler you can use :class shorthand

Comment: Nice and simple solution!

Comment: For anyone whose linter shouts at them over `'$route' ()` , you can also just write `$route(){}`  and it works fine. Not sure why examples show this as a string.

Answer (score 4):

You could give this a try:

```
<template>
    <header id="header">
        <nav class="navbar mynavbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="logo" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><router-link @click.native="closeMenu()" to="/home"><a>Home</a></router-link></li>
                        <li><router-link @click.native="closeMenu()" to="/about"><a>About Us</a></router-link></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container -->
        </nav>
    </header>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            closeMenu() {
                $('#navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

With vue3 and bootstrap5, adding this to the router-link element:

```
data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse"
```

did not work for me: the menu would close without the link being followed.
So, I added this to router/index.js:

```
router.beforeEach(() => {
    document.getElementById('navbarCollapse').classList.remove('show');
})
```

with navbarCollapse being the id of the div holding the menu/nav items.
It seemed to do the trick.

If necessary you can adjust the hamburger button state: its class list would need to contain "collapsed" and aria-expanded set to "false".
This gets corrected though when the user clicks the button again, so I didn't opt to write that code.

Comment: I was just gonna say, can't believe no one suggested router.beforeEach(), it is the obvious choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/) and vue-router.

```js
<script>
    export default {
        watch: {
          '$route' () {
                const element = document.querySelector("#nav-collapse");
                let isShown = element.classList.contains("show");
                if(isShown){
                    this.$root.$emit('bv::toggle::collapse', 'nav-collapse')
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <b-navbar toggleable="lg" type="" class="p-0">
      <b-navbar-toggle target="nav-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </b-navbar-toggle>
      <b-collapse id="nav-collapse" is-nav>
          <div class="nav-wrapper w-100">
             <ul class="app-navigation__list">
                <router-link to="/whatever" tag="li" exact class="app-navigation__list__item">
                    <a href="">
                        <span class="link-text">Home</span>
                    </a>
                </router-link>
                <router-link to="/whatever" tag="li" exact class="app-navigation__list__item">
                    <a href="">
                        <span class="link-text">About</span>
                    </a>
                </router-link>
                <router-link to="/whatever" tag="li" exact class="app-navigation__list__item">
                    <a href="">
                        <span class="link-text">Store</span>
                    </a>
                </router-link>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </b-collapse>
  </b-navbar>
</template>
```

Comment: add some explanation to the answer

Comment: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/collapse#comp-ref-b-collapse-rootEventListeners

Above snippet is watching for route change and then it will get the element by id `#nav-collapse`. Bootstrap adds a class namely `show` when it gets expanded on hamburger click. if its true it will trigger the toggle method which is mentioned in bootstrap-vue docs.

Comment: I've updated my answer, have a look for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but my answer might help someone.
do this in your router/index.js

```
    const router = createRouter({}); //P.S I am using Vue3
```

then add this before each route entering like so.

```
    router.beforeEach(() => {
        $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide'); //Be sure to import jquery
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this is such a simple task, I try to make it as simple as my simple website.

```
     Vue.mixin((()=> {
let store = Vue.observable({
    indexMenu: false,
})
return{
    computed: {
        menu: {
            get() {
                return store.indexMenu
            },
            set(val) {
                store.indexMenu = val
            }
        }
    },
    watch: {
        '$route' () {
            this.menu = false
        }
    }
}})())
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    router.beforeEach((from,to,next) => {
           $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide'); //Be sure to import jquery
        next();
    });
```

This works